# Google Home Certification not linking My app

Tags: google-smart-home

I Have working on dev app for google home certification its working fine and got the approval and released for production but when in production i am not able to do a account linking with my app. when i checked with certification team they mentioned sending scope null in response but as per document scope is an optional parameter.
Any Idea why it is not linking?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverlow, we only accept programming-related questions here.

Answer (score 0):

The scope parameter defines additional data sent to you by Google during account linking. While it is optional, you need to verify that what you use/expect is also listed in the Scopes section in AoG Console. You can access it via Develop > Account Linking > Configure your client (optional) > Scopes